# Get ASP.NET label's text or value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to transfer a string of data from C# to JavaScript in ASP web forms. My approach is to set the data as a text for an ASP label in C# and then grab the label's text by ID in JS.

C# code (ascx.cs file):

```
    List<Event> eventList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        SPSite franasabank = new SPSite("http://lbshrptweb/sites/fransabank/");
        SPWeb calendar = franasabank.OpenWeb();
        SPList list = calendar.Lists["Fransabank Calendar"];
        eventList = new List<Event>();
        foreach (SPListItem oItem in list.Items)
        {
            // Access each item in the list...  
            DateTime startTime = (DateTime)oItem["Start Time"];
            DateTime endTime = (DateTime)oItem["End Time"];
            string status = (String)oItem["Status"];
            string title = oItem.Title;
            string description = (String)oItem["Description"];
            Event calendar_event = new Event(startTime, endTime, status, title, description);
            eventList.Add(calendar_event);
        }
        foreach (Event item in eventList)
        {
            message += item.Title + " " + item.Description + item.StartDate + "-" + item.EndDate + "-" + item.Status + "\n";
        }

        Label1.Text = message;
    }
```

HTML snippet showing the Label (ascx file):

```
<div data-ng-app="Calendar">
   <div data-ng-controller="CalendarController" id="mycontroller">
     <div class="row " data-ng-init="Initialize()">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');
    console.log(a);
</script>
```

I'm receiving the data as null in variable 'a'. I've tried

```
var a = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
```

but it is also null

Comment: is your script in your ascx file or external?

Comment: it is in the ascx file

Comment: This sounds like a strange behaviour. What browser is used? Browsers without HTML5 support don't support script tags without type="javascript". Another idea is, are you using multiple of this user controls? Did you try to put the script part after the usercontrol implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like Javascript runs before the label is loaded

1. Place the js after the `<asp:Label>` on the page. Preferably before `</body>`:

   ```
       <script>
           var a = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');
           console.log(a);
       </script>
   </body>
   ```
2. Alternatively you can surround the code block with jQuery `$(document).ready()`:

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var a = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');
           console.log(a);
       });
   </script>
   ```